# Simple Jasmine Async Test with Inverted waitsFor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm trying to write an async test, which I've never done before.  In english the test says this:

- create a timer object with a callback
- if the timer were to be started, it'd trigger after 500ms
- the timer shouldn't be started
- confirm the callback isn't called by waiting 1000ms and checking if it was called

So, from reading the docs, and looking at some other code, I think this is how I should write it.

```
it("should create a timer not start", function (done) {
    var fail = false, timer;

    // if this test is passing, this should do nothing
    runs(function(){
        timer = new Timer(function () {
            fail = true;
            timer.pause();
        }, 500);
    });

    // if this test is passing, fail should never be true
    waitsFor(function(){
        return fail;
    }, 1000);

    // this should be called after 1 second because the previous times out
    runs(function(){
        expect(fail).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

However waitsFor is timing out, because fail should never be true.  I need waitsFor to wait the full second, and then the expect statement can run, but I need the timeout to be a good thing, not a failure (which Jasmine reports it as).

How do I do this with Jasmine?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if one has been posted or make a comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2017-07-24**
Based on @Yavin5's comment, This answer is valid for Jasmine v1.

For upgrading to Jasmine v2 please reference the documentation. https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html#section-9

For Jasmine V2 Documentation visit https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

You need to add a flag that that will become true when the async operation has completed.  That is what the `waitsFor` is waiting for. I would suggest something like

```
it("should create a timer not start", function (done) {
    var fail = false, timer, flag;

    // if this test is passing, this should do nothing
    runs(function(){
        flag = false;
        timer = new Timer(function () {
            fail = true;
            timer.pause();
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
      }, 1000);
    });

    // if this test is passing, fail should never be true
    waitsFor(function(){
        return flag;
    }, 1100);

    // this should be called after 1 second because the previous times out
    runs(function(){
        expect(fail).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just so people know, this is now out of date and deprecated as of Jasmine 2.0.0 apparently (and not working when I try it on Jasmine 2.6.0).